# Windows Vista: Ethereum Wallet not synching at all - stuck

Tags: wallets

Hello windows Vista Business user here, installed Ethereum-Wallet-win32-0-8-9. Then I bought 100 euros of ETH and had it send over to the wallet only to discover I could not synch the wallet. The synch downloads a few thousands blocks and just hangs, no progress whatsoever even after waiting three hours and trying for multiple days. I tried the time synch setting,  using the geth command, but that also does not seem to work. I have looked on the internet for days now, and I can't seem to find the answer, can someone help me with this? My download speed is 150Mb/Sec connected with UTP cable directly to the router..currently stuck at 2650384 blocks ...Sorry if I seem like a real n00b, but guess that's because I am at this topic! PS: I will be checking any (if someone replies) answers tomorrow , now its late in the evening here..

Comment: Might be a very silly question, but maybe there is a storage issue? Not enough free space? What arch of Vista Business are you using? 32 or 64bit?

Comment: No storage issue 300 GB free , Vista 64 bit, but the executable i downloaded is supposed to be for 32 and 64 bit..I disabled zonealarm, and the got a notification from windows firewall that geth.exe was trying to access the internet, so I allowed it to... now its stuck on 3% so I guess that some progress after all....although it has been stuck on there for half an hour already so not sure how much progress im actually making..